# Angular Input property not found in Angular TS file

Tags: angular

I have an error in my component html which says the property 'filters' isn't found on my `app-search-results-list` component:

[image]

However,in my component, I clearly have a filters field, decorated with the input property as required.

[image]

I haven't come across this error before so, to be safe, I added:

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
```

to my module and declared it:

```
schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
],
```

folder structure:

[image]

App Module TS:

[image]

FeaturesModule (I know I can clean this up)

[image]

Comment: Is this something that is actually affecting your running app or is it just about your IDE (whatever it is) displaying an error when it shouldn't be?

Comment: Initially I thought so, but the child component (SearchResultListComponent) isn't getting the new data sent to it via the parent and console logging them in ngOnChanges.

Comment: Can we get a screenshot of your module.ts files? Have you tried checking if the [data] one works by itself without the [filters] before it?
The issue is most likely in your module.ts files somewhere.

Comment: main post updated.

Comment: Are you missing an export? Also if you have had this working in the past, did you add the property before adding the field? could be a bug with the IDE so try closing and reopening it.

Comment: I did close down the IDE and restart the whole project. The error did go away. However, ngOnChanges in SearchResultsListComponent isn't picking up the new data being sent to it.

Comment: Are you sure there is actually data being sent? Did you log filterMacroDataBy?

Comment: Yes. It logs the new values for each button I hit in the parent component.